# Get row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I get the row number in a UITableView, with ignoring the sections.

So that if I have a TableView that looks like this

```
A
    item 1
    item 2
B
    item 3
    item 4
```

I want to get 4, for when item 4 appears, not like you do if you do `indexPath.row` where you get 2 because it is the 2nd row in its section. I want to ignore the sections.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, you want to "get 4".

Comment: @rdelmar when I `NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row); ` this restarts at 0 with each new section, sorry I meant 3, because I want it to go 0,1,2,3 do you see what I mean now?

Comment: Why would you want to ignore the sections? What is your purpose for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

add the before section rows by invoke -[numberOfRowsInSection:]. The current row = the row index in the current section + all rows in before sections.

Comment: right how can I get all the rows before in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: you do not need get all rows , you just get the row numbers by numberOfRowsInSection: , you pass the section to it. For example , your row in the section 3, you just pass 2,1,0 to it , to get the rows in that section. And sum them.

Comment: okay I think i mostly get it could you post a little bit of sample code, to get me started I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You must have a model for that table that looks like this:

```
NSArray *myModel = @[ @[@"A", @[@"item1", @"item2"]], 
                      @[@"B", @[@"item3", @"item4"]] ]
```

Then the problem is solved by adding the sum of the lengths of the preceding sections to a given row.

```
- (NSInteger)flatIndexOf:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger priorSectionsCount = 0;
    for (int s=0; s<indexPath.section; ++s) {
        NSArray *section = myModel[s];
        priorSectionsCount += section[1].count;
    }
    return priorSectionsCount + indexPath.row
}
```